# Display image in cell using Jquery jTable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-jtable

I am using JQuery jTable plugin to display my table records.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jTable
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of people',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 2,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'Name ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=list',
                createAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=create',
                updateAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=update',
                deleteAction: 'PersonActionsPagedSorted.php?action=delete'
            },
            fields: {
                PersonId: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                Name: {
                    title: 'Author Name',
                    width: '40%'
                },
                Age: {
                    title: 'Age',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                RecordDate: {
                    title: 'Record date',
                    width: '30%',
                    type: 'date',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                },
                Photo: {
                    title: 'Photo',
                    width: '50%',
                    type: 'img',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false
                }
            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        $('#PeopleTableContainer').jtable('load');

    });
```

The last column as you can see is `Photo`. I have stored Photo path in corresponding table in mysql table. I want to display image in last column. Is this possible using this plugin?
I am developing it in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: The field type img is not supported as on [documentation](http://www.jtable.org/apireference#fopt-type).

Answer (score 6):

This Should Solve Your Problem:

```
Photo: {
          title: "Photo",
          width: '50%',
          edit: false,
          create: false,
          display: function (data) {
                return '<img src=' + data.record.ImageURL + ' />';
           }
 }
```